# Get next year's date

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I want to get today's day and a date which is one year after today. For example, if today is 2015-9-18, next year is 2016-9-18.

I would like to use Java `LocalDate`.

Comment: Can you use Calendar instead? Calendar has methods that easily allow you to do this.

Comment: @thatidiotguy LocalDate got even more simpler methods to do it :)

Comment: If you already know that `LocalDate` exists then why do you not simply look into its API (Javadoc) to look for the appropriate methods? The answer is so overly simple to discover.

Answer (score 8):

The current date is simply retrieved with:

```
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
```

Then, you can add one year to this date, using the method [`plusYears(years)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusYears-long-):

```
LocalDate oneYearAfter = now.plusYears(1);
```

[`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) contains various methods to ease the task of adding or subtracting a temporal amount (like [`plusDays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusDays-long-), [`plusMonths`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusMonths-long-); the most general being [`plus(amount, unit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plus-long-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) adding the amount given for the specified unit of time).